# Have I broken the Access Database Engine again?

Tags: ms-access, ms-jet-ace

While testing the below SQL code for [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594064/merging-records-with-consecutive-dates/1595348#1595348), I got the following errors:

- mdb via OLE DB: "Catastrophic
  failure"
- accdb via OLE DB: (blank message)
- Access2007 Query object: "Unknown
  Access Database Error"

I'm using a new clean database file. The [showplan.out](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5064388.html) execution plan doesn't contain anything useful; I've posted the contents below.

Other than declaring the Access Database Engine unfit for purpose (!!), is there anything I can do?

```
Sub Discon()

  Const USE_MDB As Long = 1
  Const USE_ACCDB As Long = 2

  Dim version As Long

  ' Hard code which version of the
  ' Access Database Engine to use

  version = USE_MDB

  Dim fullFileName As String
  Dim conString As String

  If version = USE_MDB Then

    fullFileName = Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
    conString = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & fullFileName

  Else

    fullFileName = Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.accdb"
    conString = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & fullFileName

  End If

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill fullFileName
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
  With cat

    ' Create a new database file in user's temp folder
    .Create conString

    With .ActiveConnection

      Dim Sql As String

      ' Create a new base base with data (required to
      ' be able to later create a virtual table)

      Sql = _
      "CREATE TABLE Customers (" & _
      "CustomerID CHAR(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE);"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID)" & _
      " VALUES ('ANTON');"
      .Execute Sql

      ' Create a virtual (viewed) table
      Sql = _
      "CREATE VIEW TableA AS  " & _
      "SELECT DT1.ID, DT1.[Date], DT1.Supplier_ID " & _
      "FROM ( " & _
      "      SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS ID, '2009-10-23 00:00:00' AS [Date], " & _
      "             1 AS Supplier_ID FROM Customers " & _
      "      UNION ALL  " & _
      "      SELECT DISTINCT 2, '2009-10-23 00:00:00', 1 FROM Customers" & _
      "      UNION ALL  " & _
      "      SELECT DISTINCT 3, '2009-10-24 00:00:00', 2 FROM Customers " & _
      "      UNION ALL  " & _
      "      SELECT DISTINCT 4, '2009-10-25 00:00:00', 2 FROM Customers " & _
      "      UNION ALL  " & _
      "      SELECT DISTINCT 5, '2009-10-26 00:00:00', 1  FROM Customers " & _
      "     ) AS DT1;"
      .Execute Sql

      ' Create VIEWs based on the virtual table

      Sql = _
      "CREATE VIEW TableA_StartDates (Supplier_ID, start_date) " & _
      "AS " & _
      "SELECT T1.Supplier_ID, T1.[Date] " & _
      "  FROM TableA AS T1 " & _
      " WHERE NOT EXISTS ( " & _
      "                   SELECT * " & _
      "                     FROM TableA AS T2 " & _
      "                    WHERE T2.Supplier_ID = T1.Supplier_ID " & _
      "                          AND DATEADD('D', -1, T1.[Date]) = T2.[Date] " & _
      "                  );"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "CREATE VIEW TableA_EndDates (Supplier_ID, end_date) " & _
      "AS " & _
      "SELECT T3.Supplier_ID, T3.[Date] " & _
      "  FROM TableA AS T3 " & _
      " WHERE NOT EXISTS ( " & _
      "                   SELECT * " & _
      "                     FROM TableA AS T4 " & _
      "                    WHERE T4.Supplier_ID = T3.Supplier_ID " & _
      "                          AND DATEADD('D', 1, T3.[Date]) = T4.[Date] " & _
      "                  );"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "CREATE VIEW TableA_Periods (Supplier_ID, start_date, end_date) " & _
      "AS " & _
      "SELECT DISTINCT T5.Supplier_ID, " & _
      "       ( " & _
      "        SELECT MAX(S1.start_date) " & _
      "          FROM TableA_StartDates AS S1 " & _
      "         WHERE S1.Supplier_ID = T5.Supplier_ID " & _
      "               AND S1.start_date <= T5.[Date] " & _
      "       ), " & _
      "       ( " & _
      "        SELECT MIN(E1.end_date) " & _
      "          FROM TableA_EndDates AS E1 " & _
      "         WHERE E1.Supplier_ID = T5.Supplier_ID " & _
      "               AND T5.[Date] <= E1.end_date " & _
      "       )         " & _
      "  FROM TableA AS T5;"
      .Execute Sql

      ' Attempt to use the nested VIEWs in a query

      Sql = _
      "SELECT * FROM TableA_Periods AS P1;"

      Dim rs

      On Error Resume Next
      Set rs = .Execute(Sql)

      If Err.Number = 0 Then
        MsgBox rs.GetString
      Else
        MsgBox _
            Err.Number & ": " & _
            Err.Description & _
            " (" & Err.Source & ")"
      End If

      On Error GoTo 0

    End With
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

This is the contents of showplan.out:

```
--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
- End inputs to Query -

01) Insert into 'Customers'



--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
- End inputs to Query -

01) Insert into 'Customers'



--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
- End inputs to Query -

      store result in temporary table
      store result in temporary table
01) Union result of '00)' and result of '00)'
      store result in temporary table
02) Union result of '01)' and result of '01)'
      store result in temporary table
03) Union result of '02)' and result of '02)'
      store result in temporary table
04) Union result of '03)' and result of '03)'



--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
- End inputs to Query -

      store result in temporary table
      store result in temporary table
01) Union result of '00)' and result of '00)'
      store result in temporary table
02) Union result of '01)' and result of '01)'
      store result in temporary table
03) Union result of '02)' and result of '02)'
      store result in temporary table
04) Union result of '03)' and result of '03)'
05) Restrict rows of result of 04)
      by scanning
      testing expression "Not "



--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
- End inputs to Query -

      store result in temporary table
      store result in temporary table
01) Union result of '00)' and result of '00)'
      store result in temporary table
02) Union result of '01)' and result of '01)'
      store result in temporary table
03) Union result of '02)' and result of '02)'
      store result in temporary table
04) Union result of '03)' and result of '03)'
05) Restrict rows of result of 04)
      by scanning
      testing expression "Not "



--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
- End inputs to Query -

      store result in temporary table
      store result in temporary table
01) Union result of '00)' and result of '00)'
      store result in temporary table
02) Union result of '01)' and result of '01)'
      store result in temporary table
03) Union result of '02)' and result of '02)'
      store result in temporary table
04) Union result of '03)' and result of '03)'
05) Restrict rows of result of 04)
      by scanning
      testing expression "Not "



--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
- End inputs to Query -

      store result in temporary table
      store result in temporary table
01) Union result of '00)' and result of '00)'
      store result in temporary table
02) Union result of '01)' and result of '01)'
      store result in temporary table
03) Union result of '02)' and result of '02)'
      store result in temporary table
04) Union result of '03)' and result of '03)'
05) Restrict rows of result of 04)
      by scanning
      testing expression "Not "



--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
- End inputs to Query -

      store result in temporary table
      store result in temporary table
01) Union result of '00)' and result of '00)'
      store result in temporary table
02) Union result of '01)' and result of '01)'
      store result in temporary table
03) Union result of '02)' and result of '02)'
      store result in temporary table
04) Union result of '03)' and result of '03)'
      store result in temporary table



--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
- End inputs to Query -

      store result in temporary table
      store result in temporary table
01) Union result of '00)' and result of '00)'
      store result in temporary table
02) Union result of '01)' and result of '01)'
      store result in temporary table
03) Union result of '02)' and result of '02)'
      store result in temporary table
04) Union result of '03)' and result of '03)'
      store result in temporary table



--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
- End inputs to Query -

      store result in temporary table
      store result in temporary table
01) Union result of '00)' and result of '00)'
      store result in temporary table
02) Union result of '01)' and result of '01)'
      store result in temporary table
03) Union result of '02)' and result of '02)'
      store result in temporary table
04) Union result of '03)' and result of '03)'
      store result in temporary table



--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
Table 'Customers'
- End inputs to Query -

      store result in temporary table
      store result in temporary table
01) Union result of '00)' and result of '00)'
      store result in temporary table
02) Union result of '01)' and result of '01)'
      store result in temporary table
03) Union result of '02)' and result of '02)'
      store result in temporary table
04) Union result of '03)' and result of '03)'
      store result in temporary table
```

Comment: +1 for your question title as it made me laugh, can't help though unfortunately as I sadly left Access behind many years ago.

Comment: Is this a Jet 4.0 thing or can you reproduce it in an earlier version?

Comment: @heferav: "can you reproduce it in an earlier version?" -- Not possible: earlier versions did not support CREATE VIEW nor EXISTS. "Is this a Jet 4.0 thing" -- I can reproduce it in a later version being ACE, the version of the engine for Access2007.

Comment: What are you attempting to do. I certainly don't understand what you're trying to test here at all. It seems unnatural to me to utilize DAO to create Jet/ACE data stores from Access. The equation flips to ADO when your development environment is not Access, but I just don't see the justification for using the non-native data interface layer here.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "What are you attempting to do" -- see HansUp's answer. His analysis is spot on i.e. 'materialize' a table on the fly. Explains it better than I did :)

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "It seems unnatural to me to utilize DAO to create Jet/ACE data stores from Access" -- indeed: you prefer a GUI designer to a command line or raw code. Horses for courses ;)

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "I just don't see the justification for using the non-native data interface layer here" -- it's very simple: my SQL and ADO skills far outweigh my DAO skills. I guess the CREATE VIEW SQL DDL can be replaced with manipulation of QueryDef objects in DAO and the EXISTS subquery can be replaced with join syntax. But I don't see a justification for preferring DAO either... unless it doesn't crash, that is! Perhaps you could try a DAO translation yourself...?

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "using the non-native data interface layer here" -- I know you don't get it but the OLE DB providers I'm using *are* native to the Access Database Engine. Do you really want to debate this every time somebody mentions ADO in the context of the Access Database Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the Access Database Engine unfit for purpose (!!). These are vanilla queries and should work without error.

Comment: totally agree. I detest MS Access / Jet.. I love Access Data Projects- which is a more efficient way to communicate between SQL Server and MS Access. I'm excited for the next generation of true client-server software from MS Access 2013.

Comment: @AaronKempf: Aaron, so good to hear from you again. We've been trading shots for years and this might be one of the few occasions when we are in agreement. For a trip down memory lane, see this: http://www.mofeel.net/1-microsoft-public-access-adp-sqlserver/2808-3.aspx

Comment: yah.. I try to be a little more eloquent now :)